# Dart2, How can avoid "The method '[]' was called on null." on LIST

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using list data like this

```
List myList = someRequest();//ex)[{a:a,b:b},{c:c,d:d}] or null;
something(myList[0]); // error The method '[]' was called on null.
```

If i used map, I can avoid like this

`(myList ?? {})['0'];`

but I have to use List

How can avoid error like "myList?[0]";

Comment: try `myList.isEmpty ? []: myList.first`

Comment: thank you @TamilSelvanC  but If myList is NULL, it's also error :(

Comment: try `(myList?.first ?? [])` if null means it returns `[]` else first element in the list

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28389

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It fixed in null-safety, we can use this.

`myList?[0]`